# how to get the value of the selected tags for updating purpsoes?

Tags: php, mysql

I am still a beginner to PHP but I have a little problem, I guess. I can already insert a data in my database. But, I cannot EDIT it. When I tried to update / edit my sub-categories input, the record will be deleted. The only thing that I can update is my selected option but not updating my sub-categories (remains the same), But, when I tried to update my sub-categories input AND selected option, the update is working but if I want to update only the sub-categories, the record will be gone.

```
          <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Sub-Categories</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">    
                                     <input type="hidden" name="sub_categories_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                <div class="form-group">

                          <label for="categories" class=" form-control-label">Categories</label>
                                <select name="categories_id" required class="form-control">
                                    <option value= ""><?php echo $categories; ?></option>
                             <?php
                                  $sql = "select * from categories where status='1'";
                                    $result = $con->query($sql);
                                 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                        if($row['id']==$categories){
                                            echo "<option value=".$row['id']." selected>".$row['categories']."</option>";
                                        }else{
                                            echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['categories']."</option>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                    ?>
                     </select>
                         </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="sub_categories" class=" form-control-label">Sub-Categories</label>
                                <input type="text" name="sub_categories" id = "sub_categories" placeholder="Enter Sub-Categories" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $sub_categories; ?>">
                            </div>
                                  
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update_item"><i class="fas fa-edit"> Edit </i></button> 
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">  <i class="fas fa-times-circle"> Cancel </i> </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

MY PHP:

```
                        if(isset($_POST['update_item'])){
                        $sub_categories_id = $_POST['sub_categories_id'];
                        $categories = $_POST['categories'];
                        $sub_categories = $_POST['sub_categories'];
                        $sql = "update sub_categories set categories_id='$categories',sub_categories='$sub_categories' where id='$sub_categories_id'";
                        if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                            echo '<script>window.location.href="sub.php"</script>';
                        } else {
                            echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Check the values you are receiving in the `$_POST` field. My guess is you are missing any/some of the values...

Comment: @Luuk, I tried changing the query as only I can edit the sub_categories input and it is working. I also made an edit from the one I posted and it is when I tried to edit both of the value, the update is working but when I tried to update only the sub-categories input, the record will be gone.

Comment: Then you need to do some more debugging

Comment: Tried it for hours and still cannot figured it out that's why I asked here :/

Comment: Sorry, i am not going to debug your code...